# Вы ещё не ставили меток?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В оригинале там:

> You have not participated in any tags

Что как бы подразумевает, что пользователь не контрибьютил в посты по этой метке. Совсем иной смысл.

https://ru.traducir.win/string/4426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, текст сменится при написании ответа/вопроса по метке. Тогда предлагаю вариант:

> У вас ещё нет сообщений ни по одной метке